# How do i achieve this with custom clipper in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to achieve the container form in flutter

[image]

I want to create a container like the one shown in the image above. I can add a background Image myself, I just want to know how to create that container

Comment: ClipPath will work,

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312

Comment: You can try googling "flutter bezier curve", you will find multiple solutions on how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom paint designing to achieve this.